# Efficient Algorithm to determine highly composited numbers

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, efficiency

Im writing an algorithm to determine highly composited numbers.
But it's very unefficient with $\Omega(f(n)) = n³$.
Does someone know how i can make my code more efficient. Is my approach ok?

Here is my code:

```
import tools.Tools;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class HighCompositeNumbers {

ArrayList<Long> hcnList = new ArrayList<>();

public HighCompositeNumbers(){
    hcnList.add(1L);
}

public TreeMap<Long, Long> primeFac(long n){
    final long limit = n;
    TreeMap<Long, Long> map = new TreeMap<>();
    for (long i=2; i<=limit/2+1; i+=1){
        long counter = 0;
        if (n % i == 0) map.put(i, 0L);
        while (n % i == 0) {
            n /= i;
            counter++;
        }
        if (counter != 0) map.put(i, counter);
    }
    return map;
}

public long numberOfDivisors(long n){
    TreeMap<Long, Long> map = primeFac(n);
    long divisors = 1;
    for (Long l : map.values()){
        divisors *= (l + 1);
    }
    return divisors;
}

public boolean isHighlyComposite(long n){
    long numOfDiv = numberOfDivisors(n);
    for (long i = n-1; i>=hcnList.get(hcnList.size()-1); i--){
        if (numberOfDivisors(i) >= numOfDiv) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long max = Tools.nextLong("max: ");
    HighCompositeNumbers hcn = new HighCompositeNumbers();
    //Tools.printHashMap(hcn.primeFac(max));

    for (long i=2L; i<= max; i++){
        if (hcn.isHighlyComposite(i)) hcn.hcnList.add(i);
    }

    System.out.println(hcn.hcnList);

}
}
```

Comment: Please replace your code with pseudocode. Questions involving particular programming languages are usually off-topic here. We're interested in algorithms, not a particular implementation.

Comment: Do you mean $f(n) = \Omega(n^3)$ rather than the other way around?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Questions about code are off-topic here.  Please replace the code with concise pseudocode.  Also, I can't understand what you're asking.  Please give a self-contained definition of what you mean by "highly composited numbers".  Also, what are the inputs to your algorithm, and what should the outputs be?  What is $n$?  If you encountered this problem somewhere, please provide a reference/link to where you found it.

Answer (score 2):

As in many cases, read the problem carefully first. The problem asks for all numbers that have more divisors than any small numbers. Nobody asks you to determine the number of divisors of lots of numbers.

First write down the formula how to calculate the number of divisors of n, given its factorisation into prime numbers. Then figure out rules that say what kinds of prime factors a highly composite number might have. Quite obviously a highly composite number must be a product $2^a·3^b·5^c·7^d...$ where a ≥ b ≥ c ≥ d and so on. That's because if for example a < b, then $2^b·3^a$ would be smaller than $2^a·3^b$ but have the same number of prime factors.

That's just the start of it, but this should already help you to find highly composite numbers up to n a lot, lot faster than O (n).

Comment: I think this is a very interesting observation. There is more mentioned about it on the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_composite_number#Prime_factorization). There's also a paper [here](http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/julianmanuscript3.pdf) about an algorithm to quickly identify highly-composite numbers using these principles. Although this algorithm seems to be slightly incorrect missing 1 out of the first 1000 highly composite numbers. More discussion on this and another highly composite algorithm [here](http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/highly.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could create something similar to the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), except instead of only iterating up to $\sqrt{n}$ you would need to iterate all the way up to $n$. Each iteration you would tally up the amount of divisors a particular number has.

```
arr = list of length n
for i = 1 to n:
  for j = i to n by i:
    arr[j] += 1

curr = arr[0]
for i = 1 to n:
  if arr[i] > curr:
    // i is highly composite!!!
    curr = arr[i]
```

The complexity can be represented by a summation:

$$
\begin{align}
f(n) & = cn + \frac{cn}{2} + \frac{cn}{3} + \dots + c\\
& = cn \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{i}\\
& = cn \cdot H_n
\end{align}$$
where $H_n$ is the $n$th [Harmonic Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). $H_n$ is $\Theta(\log n)$, proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306371/simple-proof-of-showing-the-harmonic-number-h-n-theta-log-n).

It follows that this algorithm runs in $\Theta(n \log n)$.